# MySQL : Get latest SCORE for each users where quiz_id = something

Tags: mysql, distinct

So here's my table :

```
id     |     quiz_id     |     user_id     |     date_replied     |     score

1             1                  1           2014-06-04 10:11:47         50
2             1                  1           2014-06-04 20:52:53         90
3             1                  5           2014-06-05 14:22:59         80
4             1                  5           2014-06-06 18:23:41         70
```

What I want is to get the latest `score` for each `user_id` where the `quiz_id` is 1 for example.

So for the `quiz_id` = `1`; it would return :

```
id     |     quiz_id     |     user_id     |     date_replied     |     score

2             1                  1           2014-06-04 20:52:53         90
4             1                  5           2014-06-06 18:23:41         70
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL ?

Thank you !

Comment: In which type of application do you use it ?

Comment: try this one No need joining here `SELECT * FROM table where quiz_id=1  group by user_id order by date_replied DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.* 
from your_table t1
join
(
  select user_id, max(date_replied) as mdate
  from your_table
  where quiz_id = 1
  group by user_id
) t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.date_replied = t2.mdate
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have a " Unknown column 't2.user_id' in 'on clause' " error with this